# PaperTrail: How to handle "Data too long for column 'object'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I have some pretty long texts in my database, and they seem to exceed PaperTrail's `object` max length (which on MySQL seems to be 64kb for `:text` fields).

I think that this limit is exceeded pretty fast, as PaperTrail always stores the before and after values of each versioned field in one single `object` field. So e.g. when versioning 1 text field of a model, the text field must not exceed ~1/2th of its possible max length, otherwise the limit of the `object` field is already exceeded. If you have 2 text fields, the text fields must not exceed ~1/4th of its their max length.

So how should I handle this issue? Should I simply use bigger field type for `object`? I just can't find one which works in Rails migrations, so this doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by increasing the limit of the `object` column.

```
class ChangeVersionsObjectToMediumText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Needed because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088654/papertrail-how-to-handle-data-too-long-for-column-object
    change_column :versions, :object, :text, limit: 16.megabytes - 1
  end
end
```

Comment: As of PT 4.0.0.rc2, the generated migration does exactly this. See https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/commit/4ba85e2548af43aa5ea09311cb56932a9153d99f. I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.